# MySQL : How to aggregate table column into a list and count?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in **MySql** like :

```
URL       Browser
A         Chrome
B         Chrome 
C         Firefox
A         Chrome
A         Firefox
A         Opera
A         Chrome
B         Chrome
B         Firefox
C         Tor
```

The `URL` column has a wide range of data, but the Browser column has a limited set. I want to aggregate on the URL column and get the top counts for each browser in a list in descending order, like :

```
URL      FrequentlyUsedBrowser 
A        [(Chrome,3),(Firefox,1),(Opera,1)]
B        [(Chrome,2),(Firefox,1)]
C        [(Chrome,1),(Tor,1)]
```

I have been writing `SQL` for it to use window partition to get the count as one entry for each browser, but not been able to get it into a list.

Comment: What is your actual SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres) ?

Comment: Sorry, It is MySQL .

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 5):

Here's your query. This is achievable using `group_concat()`

```
select url
    , concat('[', group_concat('(', browser, ',', ct, ')'), ']') as FrequentlyUsedBrowser 
    from 
    (select count(1) ct, url, browser from test
        group by url, browser) t1
group by url
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=6dddnpj7pn)