# How to find the maximum counts of clicks made by customers for a particular date range?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

```
Customers Table

ID, CustomerName
8977, John
8978, Oliver
8976, Graham
```

```
ClickInfo Table

Date, ID, CustomerID
2019-11-05, 123422, 8977
2019-11-05, 123433, 8977
2019-11-07, 123463, 8978
2019-11-05, 134556, 8976
```

What I need is for a date range from 2019-11-01 to 2019-11-10 (1st to 10th November),

1. Number of unique customers who click the website atleast once.
2. Print the CustomerID and CustomerName of the person who clicked maximum number of clicks each day. If there is more than one person who have the same maximum number of clicks, print the customer with the lowest CustomerID(in case of 8976 and 8978 we'll choose 8976 because it is lower). All this should be printed in ascending order of dates.

Now for the second part I have tried doing the following :

```
select ClickInfo.Date,
count(ClickInfo.CustomerID) as clicks,
Customers.ID,
Customers.CustomerName
from ClickInfo
left join Customers
on Customers.ID = ClickInfo.CustomerID
where Date between '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-10'
group by ClickInfo.Date
order by ClickInfo.Date ASC;
```

Now the result is giving me the Count of clicks for a particular day but not the max clicks and who did it. I am new to SQL and not able to think beyond this. Can you help here with explanation?

Comment: Try to use MAX() function in the query https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_max.asp

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group first by `customerId` not by `date`.

```
select ClickInfo.Date,
    sum(case when coalesce(ClickInfo.CustomerID, 0) != 0 then 1 else 0 end) as clicks,
    Customers.ID,
    Customers.CustomerName
from ClickInfo
left join Customers on Customers.ID = ClickInfo.CustomerID
where Date between '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-10'
group by Customers.ID,
    Customers.CustomerName, ClickInfo.Date
order by ClickInfo.Date ASC;
```

Comment: @RetardedSatan . . . I honestly do not see how this answers your question.  This returns a separate row for each customer, rather than the "best" customer on each date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, at least, more worst if OP accepted a copied answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58870475/mysql-how-to-aggregate-table-column-into-a-list-and-count/58870535#58870535

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with window functions and aggregation:

```
select cc.*
from (select ci.Date, c.ID, c.CustomerName
             count(*) as num_clicks_customer,
             sum(count(*)) over (partition by ci.date) as total_clicks,
             row_number() over (partition by ci.Date order by count(*) desc, c.id) as seqnum        
      from ClickInfo ci left join
           Customers c
           on c.ID = ci.CustomerID
      where ci.Date between '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-10' and
            ci.CustoemrId <> 0
      group by ci.Date, c.ID
     ) cc
where seqnum = 1
order by ci.Date ASC;
```